# MySQL JOIN to JSON array

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo, join

I'm building a HTTP API and this part should return a JSON list of posts and their attached photos, like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "788",
        "content": "Foo bar! Foo foo, bar bar.",
        "photos": [181, 282, 182]
    },
    ...
]
```

And this is my PHP code handling the request:

```
// get all the posts and their photos
$st = $db->prepare ('SELECT * FROM `posts` ' .
                    'LEFT JOIN `photos` ON `photo_post` = `post_id`');
$st->execute ();

// init our results array
$posts = array ();

// get the first post (plus it's JOINed photo)
$row = $st->fetch (PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
// if there's more left
while (false !== $row) {
    // init our post array
    $post = array (
        'id' => $row->id,
        'content' => $row->content,
        'photos' => array ()    // to fill with the photos
    );
    do {
        // don't add a `null` if there's no photos
        if (null !== $row->screenshot)
            $post ['photos'] [] = $row->photo_id;
    // get the row, repeat if it's another photo
    } while (false !== ($row = $st->fetch (PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) &&
             $row->id === $post ['id']);

    // add this post to the list
    $posts [] = $post;
}

// and send it back
echo json_encode ($posts);
```

Pretty simple `JOIN` parsing job, right?  But the code is anything but nice or simple!

**How can I parse MySQL's `JOIN` results elegantly into the JSON heirarchy that I need?**

Comment: Recommend Using a PHP model to extract the attributes.
Then Serialize this PHP Model with a JSON Serializer.

Comment: @Muks on a more complex project I'd agree, but I'd rather keep things minimal/simple here instead of implementing a Model framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not vastly different but you might think its a little easier to read and follow and probably therefore debug.

With this code everything can be done within a single loop rather than the more complex multiple loop while/do that you originally used.

This also makes use of the `stdClass` provided by PHP to generate an array of objects as per your requirement, where your code was creating an array of arrays.

```
// get all the posts and their photos
$st = $db->prepare ('SELECT * FROM `posts` ' .
                    'LEFT JOIN `photos` ON `photo_post` = `post_id`');
$st->execute ();

// init our results array
$posts = array ();

$lastPostId = NULL;

// get the first post (plus it's JOINed photo)
while ( $post = $st->fetch (PDO::FETCH_OBJ) ) {

    if ( $lastPostId != $post->id ) {
        if ( $lastPostId !== NULL ) {
            // add this obj to the post array
            $posts[] = $tPost;
        }
        // start a new temp object
        $tPost          = stdClass();
        $tPost->id      = $post->id;
        $tPost->content = $post->content;
        $tPost->photos  = array();
    }

    // Add photo_id to current tPost obj
    $tPost->photos[] = $post->photo_id;

    $lastPostId = $post->id;
}

// and send it back
echo json_encode($posts);
```

Comment: This is great!  I had a solution like this with arrays, but PHP's buggy array pass-by-reference behavior killed it.  `stdClass` solves that nicely.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of MySQL's [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) function which will return a comma separated list of photoIds. e.g. 1,2,3,4,5

If there are no photos, an empty string is returned. Explode returns an empty array if passed an empty string.

```
// get all the posts and their photos

$st = $db->prepare ('
    SELECT `posts`.post_id as id, `posts`.content, GROUP_CONCAT(`photos`.id) AS photoIds
    FROM `posts` 
    LEFT JOIN `photos` ON `photo_post` = `post_id`
    GROUP BY `posts`.post_id
');

$st->execute ();

// init our results array
$posts = [];

$rows = $st->fetchAll (\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $row['photos'] = explode(',', $row['photoIds']);
    $posts[] = $row;
}

// and send it back
echo json_encode ($posts);
```